# O que é e como se pronuncia "fixe"?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, pronúncia, informalidade

Sou brasileiro. No entanto, já ouvi o termo *fixe* sendo usado por portugueses.

O que significa esse termo? E como se pronuncia? Com `x` como em *táxi*, ou como em *mexer*?

Comment: Pense em *peixe* em inglês :)

Comment: @bfavaretto para o significado ou para a pronúncia? :)

Comment: Hahaha, para a pronúncia. O significado é *legal*, *bacana*, *da hora*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

O "x" de *fixe* pronuncia-se como o *ch* de *ficha. Significado: *ser fixe* significa ’ser porreiro’ (como "cool" em "to be a cool guy") ou ’ser legal’ no Brasil.

**Observação**: mas a forma verbal *fixe* do verbo *fixar*, por exemplo em "talvez fixe bem, se ler o texto várias vezes" lê-se /fiks/.

Comment: Ser porreiro também não é comum no Brasil, só entendi quando li "cool"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acrescentei o significado "bom".

Comment: Não sei se concorda comigo, mas "bom" soa como "pessoa boa", mesmo que seja o termo certo, não é tão comum, que tal usar "legal".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo. Só não usei "legal" porque é um brasileirismo em Português de Portugal. Mas vou incluir.

Comment: Sim, mas o autor perguntou do termo comum em Portugal, provavelmente a resposta poderia ser para o entendimento em outras regiões, como no inglês :) -- Obrigado pela edição!

Comment: @AméricoTavares Se pronuncia o "e" no final? Ou a pronúncia é "físhi"?

Comment: @BrunoLopes  Sim, pronuncia-se "fiche".

Comment: @BrunoLopes [ouve aqui](https://translate.google.pt/#pt/en/fixe)

Answer (score 10):

O termo *fixe* se pronuncia exatamente igual a *fish* ( em inlgês ) e significa ’**legal**’.

Algumas utilizações:

- Tás fixe? - Estás bem?
- Bué'da fixe isto. - Muito legal isto
- Nossa que fixe - nossa que legal.

Comment: Atenção que a pronúnica não é exatamente igual, apenas muito semelhantes. O inglês possui várias fonéticas da letra i, entre elas o "ɪ" das palavras _fish_, _it_, _fix_ e _mist_. O i do _fixe_ pronuncia-se como o _ea_ do _beat_  ou o _ee_ do _meet_.

Comment: Para este falante do inglês, "fish" e "fixe" não parecem iguais, nem muito semelhantes. Parecem distinctos, como por exemplo "tchau" e "chão" parecem distinctos. Acho "fish" mais parecido com "féch" do que "fixe".

Comment: @DanGetz tens toda a razão. É [fixe](https://translate.google.pt/#pt/en/fixe) (ouçam)

Comment: Nunca ouvi ninguém dizer "nossa que fixe"... "nossa" não é usado como penso seja usado no Brazil.

Comment: Alguém me explica a frase "Bué'da fixe isto"? Não faz sentido nenhum pra mim, como brasileiro. Interessante a diferença do pt-PT e pt-BR.

Answer (score 2):

A palavra "**fixe**" tem o mesmo significado de "**bom**", "**legal**".

- Você pode verificar o **significado de qualquer palavra** neste ótimo dicionário online: [https://dicionario.priberam.org/](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fixe).
- Você pode verificar a **pronúncia de palavras na voz de nativos** da língua portuguesa aqui: https://forvo.com/pronounce/

Comment: Zewill, bem-vindo ao site [EXCLAMAÇÃO]. Tás num ótimo começo, já tendo referência nos teus textos. Uma opinião minha é que o Forvo pode ter pronúncia bem várias e **não padrões**, assim pode ser interessante usar referências mais profissionais com pronúncia, como a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/fixe) e [Portal da Língua](http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?action=lemma&lemma=125873&highlight=^fixe$). Para uma pergunta sobre pronúncias regionais, o Forvo já se torna bem mais interessante, mas não é um mau site n'ambos os casos.

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões @Schilive!

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o dicionario [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fixe):

O x pronuncia-se como ch, portanto /fiʃ(ɨ)/.

Tem significado semelhante a *legal*, ou seja, ’bom, porreiro, simpático’, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Fixe* é termo bastante usado em Angola. Significa ’bem,  agradável, legal, bacana’.

Comment: José, bem-vindo ao site. Poderia melhorar bastante a tua resposta, dando mais pormenores sobre o uso de *fixe* em Angola. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/why-is-fixe-a-cool-thing-in-portugal?noredirect=1&lq=1); na primeira resposta lá tens os vários usos em Portugal; o dicionário citado diz que alguns usos são exclusivos de Portugal, e eu pergunto-me se serão mesmo. Por exemplo, em Angola não se ouve coisas do tipo. "Então, encontramo-nos logo à noite em minha casa", e o outro responde simplesmente, "Fixe" (= 'ótimo, de acordo')?

Answer (score 0):

fixe se pronúncia com som de 'ch'
3ª pess. sing. imp. de fixar
3ª pess. sing. pres. subj. de fixar
1ª pess. sing. pres. subj. de fixar

fi·xe |ch|
(alteração de fixo)
adjetivo de dois gêneros

1. [Portugal, Informal]  Que agrada ou tem qualidades positivas (ex.: o livro é muito fixe). [Equivalente no português do Brasil: legal.] = BOM, PORREIRO
2. [Popular]  Que é fixo, firme ou seguro.
3. [Brasil]  Compacto; inteiriço; maciço.

adjetivo de dois gêneros e substantivo de dois gêneros
4. [Portugal, Informal]  Que ou quem inspira simpatia (ex.: os teus colegas são fixes). [Equivalente no português do Brasil: legal.] = PORREIRO, SIMPÁTICO

interjeição
5. [Portugal, Informal]  Usa-se para exprimir satisfação ou concordância (ex.: eles já chegaram, fixe! Fixe, já podemos ir embora). [Equivalente no português do Brasil: legal.]

substantivo masculino
6. [Termo ferroviário]   Retângulo de madeira ou ferro, sobre rodas, para sustentar a máquina do  trem.

fi·xar |cs| - Conjugar
(fixo + -ar)
verbo transitivo

1. Tornar fixo.
2. Segurar, cravar, pregar.
3. Afixar.
4. Fitar.
5. Reter (na memória).
6. Determinar, indicar com  exatidão.
7. Tornar estável.
8. [Química]  Concentrar (substância volátil).

verbo pronominal
9. Tornar-se fixo, estável, permanente.

10. Estabelecer-se.
11. Atentar, fixar a atenção.

Confrontar: fichar.
Palavras relacionadas

"fixe", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/fixe [consultado em 23-04-2021].