# Why is "fixe" a "cool" thing in Portugal?

Tags: etimologia, português-europeu, estrangeirismos

Is it because Portuguese people love fish? Or is it because fish are cool? (pun intended)

I read **fixe**'s [pronunciation question in here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/85/o-que-%C3%A9-e-como-se-pronuncia-fixe), heard the [Google Translate pronunciation](https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/fixe) and the word resembles fish(uh)... The plural is **fixes** and I assume it is pronounced as *fishesh* (google's audio is a little messed up on this).

I also found some [attempts of explaining its etymology in here](http://sicojornal.blogspot.pt/2011/01/origem-da-palavra-fixe_12.html), but the comments suggest that this is an extremely old word (probably as old as the country itself). Here are some quotes:

> - The origin of the word *fixe* is linked to the British tourists visiting the Algarve. [...]
>     The British tourism in Portugal has a long tradition (especially since the beginning of the 20th century) and one of the things that tourists loved was our cuisine, particularly the fish dishes (since "fish and chips" was barely the only fish dish they knew about).
>     Thus tourists in Portuguese restaurants would ask for fish and would savor it with great pleasure and satisfaction. So the word *fixe* in Portuguese was naturally brought up by this phenomena and it would refer to something cool and great.
> - In fact, the actor [Vasco Santana pronounces the word *fixe* in a scene](https://youtu.be/qyFkb_gjt4s?t=240) from the movie [Canção de Lisboa](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Can%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Lisboa) (1933).
> - ["A Alma e a Gente", season 5, in an episode about Sintra (#5)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQguE_2Y4rw&t=1242) after minute 20, Prof. José Hermano Saraiva says that the future [King Afonso VI (1643-1683)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afonso_VI_of_Portugal), a sickly child, would say nothing but *fixe*.

The dictionaries just provide the definition:

- [infopedia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/fixe): an exclamation that expresses pleasure, excitement, satisfaction, joy, greatness, excellency and wonder;
- [priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fixe): something that pleases or have positive qualities.

So what gives? Where does this great **fixe** comes from? Is it still fresh or is it getting stale already?

Comment: Essa explicação dos turistas cheira-me a treta. O Priberam diz que é uma alteração de "fixo", mas fica por explicar como o /ks/ passa a /ʃ/.

Comment: Armfoot, encontrei e linkei o episódio da Alma e a Gente.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (DACL) has two entries for **fixe** (/ˈfiʃ(ə)/; hear it in [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/fixe/#pt)), giving the French *fixe* (/fiks/) as its origin. Houaiss dictionary (Lisboa, 2003) however just says it is a popular modification of *fixo*, probably under French influence. I quote DACL, as it has more examples:

> **Fixe (1)**  *Feminine and masculine adjective. Colloquial*.
>   **1** Que não muda; que é seguro; firme, fixo. *Estava com medo que a escada não estivesse bem fixe e que ele caísse desamparado*.
>   **2** Que é honesto, leal; que é digno de confiança. *É um tipo fixe, não vai denunciar seja quem for*.
>   **3** Que é simpático, prestável,bom; que tem qualidades que atraem os outros.
>   **4** Que agrada, que dá prazer. *Assistimos a uma cena muito fixe. Esta casa é mesmo fixe!*
>   **5** Que é compacto, forte.
>
> **Fixe (2)** *interjection, colloquial*.
>   **1** Exclamação que exprime entusiasmo alegria. *Fixe! Este é cá dos meus! Fixe! O professor não vai dar aula.*
>   **2** Usa-se como forma de assentimento, para provar que algo fica combinado, assente.

According to Houaiss, senses 1.3 and 1.4 (‘nice, pleasing’) applies outside Brazil only; and the interjectional senses 2 in Portugal only.

Except for the French influence, which I'm not old enough to confirm personally, this matches my personal experience. *Fixe* was used where I grew up in the sense 1.1 of firmly fastened, secure. And when I started hearing it in the other senses (which, I now realise, had been in use for quite some time elsewhere) I've always relate it to firmly fastened, secure. There is a sort of logical sequence from 1.1 to 1.4. Someone who does not change and is firm (1.1) is loyal and reliable (1.2), which is good and attractive (1.3), which pleases (1.4). Meaning 1.5 comes directly from 1.1, I'd say. The interjection (2) is perfectly understandle from meanings 1.2 to 1.4.

The *fish*-origin hypothesis is just an anonymous comment in a blog, and sounds *fishy*, to put it charitably. And anyway the [1933 Vasco Santana's quote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyFkb_gjt4s&feature=youtu.be&t=240) and the [humorous weekly *Sempre Fixe*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Sempre_Fixe), published in Lisbon from 1926, do away with it:

[image]
[*Sempre Fixe*, Lisboa, 26-5-1926](http://hemerotecadigital.cm-lisboa.pt/Periodicos/SempreFixe/1926/Maio/N03/N03_master/SempreFixeN03.PDF)

The other senses of the word occur even earlier:

> Mas todo o Mundo está cheio / De que tu não me eras **fixe**.
>   —Se eu te não fôra **fixe**/ Não te andava adorando;/Pela graça dos teus olhos,/Minha alma se anda matando.
>   [(Teófilo Braga, *Cantos Populares do Archipelago Açoreano*, 1869.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Hb8GAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA130&dq=%22tu%20n%C3%A3o%20me%20eras%20fixe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj41rfI947NAhVIVRQKHTLyDdEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22tu%20n%C3%A3o%20me%20eras%20fixe%22&f=false)
>
> Agora, decidiu trabalhar na Gruna do Defunto. Apesar do tempo estar "**fixe**", eu não achei bom, porque neste mês costuma dar uns aguaceiros na serra, e qualquer agüinha do riacho toma a boca da gruna, e foi assim que morreu o primeiro que entrou. ([Lindolfo Rocha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindolfo_Rocha), *Maria Dusá*, 1910) (If this sounds like Brazilian Portuguese, it's because it is.)
>
> Vê Vossa Mercê, que fazendo eu tenção **fixe** de não meter hoje em filosofias, já entrava nelas sem querer! ([António da Costa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abade_Ant%C3%B3nio_da_Costa), *Cartas do Abade António da Costa*, 1744.)

And Portuguese historian José Hermano Saraiva says in [this episode of *A Alma e a Gente*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQguE_2Y4rw), after minute 20, that the [hapless future King Afonso VI (1643-83)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afonso_VI_of_Portugal), as a child, a slow, sickly child, would only say *fixe*. Sounds like the interjection here.

I didn’t find anyone explaining the probable French influence. A possible reason is that [French *fixe*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fixe/33907?q=fixe#33846) has had the Portuguese meaning 1.1 (‘unmovable, stable’), which likely was where all other meanings sprung form, since the 1300s [(CNRTL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/fixe).

Comment: Mas em francês _fixe_ lê-se também /ks/: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fixe#Pronunciation

Comment: Sim, sim, está indicado na minha resposta. Nesse aspeto, limito-me a reproduzir as fontes.

Comment: Ah, desculpa, tinha lido mal. Mas não havendo essa vantagem, resta saber porque alguém há de achar que vem do francês e não de "fixo", que de resto é um adjetivo muito comum e como de resto diz o Priberam. De "fixo" para "fixe" (/ks/) é uma passo muito curto (são praticamente homófonas no Algarve por exemplo).

Comment: Também pensei nisso, porquê do francês *fixe* e não do português *fixo*. A única coisa que me ocorre é que o francês *fixe* tem o mesmo significado que o português *fixe* 1.1, e há uma palavra francesa relacionada, *ficher*, que significa espetar, afundar na terra. Talvez a pronúncia do francês *fixe* fosse no passado influenciado por *ficher*.

Comment: It does make sense, those two last examples from 1910 and 1744 they do resemble more a **fix**ed state. Particularly, in the 1910 example, he says that the weather is kind of fixed (i.e. stable) but he doesn't like it. In addition if you pronounce **kse** fast enough, I imagine people omitting the **k** and just go on with the **sh** sound. Cool, or better still, **fixe**! :)

Comment: @Armfoot I agree. In the 1744 example, *fixe* clearly means *firm*, as in  sense 1.1. I think that's also the meaning in the 1910 example, but it's less clear. *Fixe* as *firm*, which I've hear as a child before I hear it as an interjection, was pronounced as *fish*.

Answer (score 3):

I got to know a guy from Cape Verde and he said "fixe" all the time. So I asked him what it meant and in Cape Verde it is equal to "legal" ou "muito bom" in Brazilian Portuguese. So if your are in Portugal or Cape Verde you can use it to say that something is cool or awesome, but if you go to Brasil and say that people will look at you weird!